# A better way of calculating top-32 file sizes for DFS folder staging size

Tags: powershell, microsoft-distributed-file-system

A common task when setting up a DFS replica is to determine the size of the 32-largest files in the replicated folder - the sum of these should be the minimum size of the staging area, according to current best practice.

A method of finding and calculating this top-32 file size is given in a Technet blog: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askds/2011/07/13/how-to-determine-the-minimum-staging-area-dfsr-needs-for-a-replicated-folder/

It relies on using `Get-ChildItem` to find all files and their sizes in a path, sort by size, discard all but the 32 largest, and then calculate the sum.

It's fine when you have a limited number of files in your path, but there are serious drawbacks when indexing a folder that has hundreds of thousands, if not millions of files. The process dumps everything into memory while it's executing - in my sample, it consumes over 2GB of virtual memory - and takes a long time, even when the individual files are quite small. The memory remains allocated until the PS instance is closed.

```
PS C:\> measure-command { (get-childitem F:\Folder\with\966693\items -recurse | 
sort-object length -descending | select-object -first 32 | 
measure-object -property length -sum).sum }
Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 6
Seconds           : 6
Milliseconds      : 641
Ticks             : 3666410633
TotalDays         : 0.00424353082523148
TotalHours        : 0.101844739805556
TotalMinutes      : 6.11068438833333
TotalSeconds      : 366.6410633
TotalMilliseconds : 366641.0633
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd be surprised if you could speed up `Get-ChildItem` much, unless you could avoid building `[IO.FileInfo]` objects for every file (.Net DirectorySearcher maybe?).

But you might be able to reduce the memory requirements by not keeping all the results, only the ongoing N largest, 100 in this example, but adjust to test memory / performance e.g.

```
$BufferSize = 100
$FileSizes = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList

Get-ChildItem 'd:\downloads' -Force -Recurse -File | ForEach {

    $null = $FileSizes.Add($_.Length)
    if ($FileSizes.Count -gt $BufferSize)
    {
        $FileSizes.Sort()
        $FileSizes.RemoveRange(0, ($BufferSize-32))
    }
}
($FileSizes[0..31] | measure-object -Sum).Sum/1GB
```

Added `-Force` parameter to gci in case some of the biggest files are hidden.

Comment: Thanks, that looks even more efficient, by dumping out the no-longer-required results. As for my results, they were pretty consistent in testing with 100K+ files in the folder trees. I wanted to fix this issue, because I was basically getting a memory leak on the server every time I tried the original process on a 1.2 million item fileset. A feature of these particular filesets is that much of them consists of files <5K in size.

Answer (score 1):

With a slight tweak - instantiating a [`System.Collections.ArrayList`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist(v=vs.110).aspx) to store the list of file lengths - the time to execute the query over the same directory is nearly halved. You're [not constantly creating/destroying a standard fixed-sized array](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/windows-powershell-cookbook/9780596528492/ch11s12.html) as you add a new item to it.

Memory usage for the Powershell process for this sample remains at less than 900MB. I also like having a variable to set to $null if I want to reuse the PS console.

```
measure command { $total = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList; 
gci F:\Folder\with\966693\items -file -r | 
ForEach { $total.Add($_.length)>$null } ; 
(($total | sort -descending | select -first 32 |measure-object -sum).sum/1GB) }
Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 3
Seconds           : 34
Milliseconds      : 215
Ticks             : 2142159038
TotalDays         : 0.00247935073842593
TotalHours        : 0.0595044177222222
TotalMinutes      : 3.57026506333333
TotalSeconds      : 214.2159038
TotalMilliseconds : 214215.9038
```

Tidier multi-line version:

```
$total = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
gci F:\Folder\with\966693\items  -file -r | ForEach { $total.Add($_.length)>$null } 
($total | sort -descending | select -first 32 | measure-object -sum).sum/1GB
```